# Class with pointers and const method

Tags: c++, constants

Suppose we have class for linked list of T.
(I don't know if code actually works)

```
template <typename T>
struct List{

   struct Node{
      T data;
      Node *next;
   };

   // add, remove etc...

   Node *locate(const T &a) const{
      for(Node *node = head; node; node = node->next)
         if (node->data == a)
            return node;

      return nullptr;
   }

private;
   Node *head;
};
```

If you inspect method `locate`, it basically can harm and ruin the linked list, even the method is marked as `const`.

I just noticed something else. Since Node is not const, Node::data can be changed as well.

Supposing this was programmer mistake, is there a C++ way this to be avoid?

> I know the method can be written as this.
>
> ```
>     const Node *locateConst(const T &a) const{
>       for(const Node *node = head; node; node = node->next)
>          if (node->data == a)
>             return node;
>
>       return nullptr;
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, "const" means "can't change this object", it does NOT mean "can't change things this object points to".

I.e. with `const List *const_list` you can't change `const_list->head`, but you can change `const_list->head->next` or `const_list->head->data`.

If you're writing a List class, then you probably want `const List` to mean "can't change things this object points to", and C++ provides the tools you need to implement List so it works that way.  But it's your job, as the author of the List class, to do that - the compiler can't just magically know that's what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeking an experimental feature, yet unavailable on many platforms. If your std libray supports, you can use `std::experimental::propagate_const<node*>` instead of naked raw pointers.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const
In the mean time, you can implement your - maybe less generic - own version.

Answer (score 0):

*is there a C++ way this to be avoid?*

No, of course not.  Programmers do have responsibilities you know.  The way the method is declared promises not to change `head`, not `*head`.